# Select box ':selected' value validation jQuery

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have to validate the selected option values on change in jQuery.  Here is the actual code and dynamic jQuery I tried.   I know I struck somewhere else, I don’t know where it is.  Would be really appreciated one if anyone can help me out on this.

I have list of rows in one main div container which are having select box with dynamically loading populated from backend.  Number of select boxes also coming dynamically rendering.  I hope that doesn’t matter.  The arrangement of the select box placement is like this…

[image]

For instance, when I select the option in first combo box, I have to validate whether the same selected option is already selected in another select boxes are not.  If it is selected, I have to show alert message saying that, you have already chosen the same value in another select box.  The same validation has to be done for all select boxes.

This is the code I tried:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.addedOptions, select.defaultSel', function () { var selCurrent = $(this).find(':selected').val();$('.confCustFormCont .confCustRow').each(function() {var selAllOtherValue = $(this).find('select option:selected').text();});});
```

This one is not working properly.  Any ideas?

Comment: share your html also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Edward, you can use the loop to get the values and then compare the current selected value. A sample for you:

```
        $("select").change(function () {
            var selectedValues = [], currentValue = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $("select").each(function () {
                selectedValues.push($(this).find("option:selected").val());
            });
            if (selectedValues.indexOf(currentvalue) > -1)
                alert("you have already selected this value, please select another one."); return false;
        });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you want to specify a group of select boxes then you can apply a class and then use that selector in the method, this would work for as many selectboxes you want

Comment: Hi D.T, it is throwing undefined error for 'currentValue'.  As the select boxes are dynamically added, I slightly modified the first line in order to get along with my html stuffs... 

$(document).on('change', 'select', function ()

Did i do any mistakes?

Comment: no its fine, just put a debugger and try to check it in console, what is returned in `$(this).find("option:selected")`. If this is returning undefined then you will get error. If it is the case then set a selected value at first which creating dynamic selectboxes, it would resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle below, you select the previous select's option by selecting its value and then match that value against the current value.

```
select1 = $('#select1');
select2 = $('#select2');
select3 = $('#select3');

$(select2).change(function() {
    var this_val = $(this).val();
    var that_val = $(select1).find('option[value="' + val + '"]').val();
    if(this_val == that_val) {
        alert("Oh no you don't");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Do this for as many select boxes you need or put it into a clever loop if you are feeling exotic...

Comment: This one is good.  But we can't predict the number select boxes.  We might have 10, or 20 in future.

Comment: That is why i said put it in a loop :-) `$('select').each(function() {});` should do